# Android Facebook SDK - part of the post remains not shown

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I'm using [phonegap-build / FacebookConnect](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/master/example/Simple/index.html)

Everything works correctly but when I put some post using Android app on the Facebook wall, most of the text remains not shown. There is not even "see more" link at the end of the part of the post. At the half of the second sentence of "description" everything breaks.

The JS function that I'm using for this Android app:

```
function facebookWallPost() {
            console.log('Debug 1');
            var params = {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                description: 'The Internet is a global system of interconnected computer networks that use the standard Internet protocol suite (TCP/IP) to serve billions of users worldwide. It is a network of networks that consists of millions of private, public, academic, business, and government networks, of local to global scope, that are linked by a broad array of electronic, wireless and optical networking technologies. The Internet carries an extensive range of information resources and services, such as the inter-linked hypertext documents of the World Wide Web (WWW) and the infrastructure to support email.'
              };
            console.log(params);
            FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
        }
```

The whole script and an example can be seen [here ...](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/master/example/Simple/index.html)

Do I need to change data structure and post params as JSON?
Thanks in advance. I appreciate any help...